# tSQL test query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Today I have been to a job interview and the interviewer gave me the question in the following image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqqll.jpg

I wrote a query, but it doesn't even come close to solving the requirements.

```
select distinct 
    id_intermediar,
    nume_intermediar,
    regiune_vanzare_intermediar,
    count(p.id_polita) as Numar_Total_Polite,
    count(o.id_obiect) over (partition by(o.id_polita)) as Numar_Total_obiecte
    count(p.id_polita) over (partition by (year(p.data_emitere_polita))) as Polite_Anul_Curent,
    sum(Prima_subscrisa) as Prima_totala,
    sum(Prima_subscrisa) over (partition by(year(data_emitere_polita))) as Prima_Anul_Curent
from 
    test_ba_polite p, test_ba_obiecteriscuri o
where 
    nume_intermediar like '%broker%' 
    and regiune_vanzare_intermediar = 'Timisoara'
group by 
    id_intermediar, nume_intermediar, regiune_vanzare_intermediar, 
    p.id_polita,o.id_polita,o.id_obiect, p.data_emitere_polita, p.Prima_subscrisa
```

Can you please help me understand how I should have solved this? Thank you.

All the best.

Comment: `select distinct` combined with `group by`... A bit odd.

Comment: Without full confidence in what "in anul curent" &c. means, I believe a self-join would have helped.

Comment: in anul curent = the current year. sorry about that

Comment: Yeah, thought so :) From a glance, it seems like "prima X..." would resolve to some `SUM( X )`. Then, when I see some "prima X where ..." on the same `X` this to me indicates that I should use at least one self-join. (`SUM( CASE X > ... )` would probably work too.)

Comment: in anul curent = the current year. so, basicly the requirements are: id_intermediar (id of agent), nume_intermediar (name of agent), regiune_intermediar (region), Nr_total_de_polite = total number of policies = a count of all policies, Nr_total_de_obiecte = total number of objects from the test_BA_obiecteRiscuri table, Nr_polite_emise_in _anul_curent = number of policies emited during the current year, Prima_subscrisa totala =  a sum of prima_subcrisa field, prima_subcrisa_in_anul_curent = sum of prima_subscrisa for the current year. sorry about missing to explain